# Not able to hover on each line in Highcharts's Parallel Coordinate chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, parallel-coordinates

I have implemented Parallel coordinate chart with Highcharts [link](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parallel-coordinates) but not able to hover on each and every line. Instead, it hover on other point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is already reported on Highcharts GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9054

To workaround, you can disable Highcharts `tooltip` and `enableMouseTracking` option and add your own event to the lines:

```
    var lines = $('.highcharts-series path');

    lines.on('mouseover', function(e) {
        var series,
            result = '',
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
            if (chart.series[i].graph.d === this.getAttribute("d")) {
                series = chart.series[i];
                i = chart.series.length;
            }
        }

        Highcharts.each(series.points, function(p) {
            result += p.category + ' ' + p.y + '<br>'
        });

        $("#tooltip").html(result);
    });
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/so52apLn/

Comment: @ppotaczed I tried this solution but didn't worked. series never got populated as (chart.series[i].graph.d === this.getAttribute("d")) condition is not satisfied. Hence, I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'points' of undefined" error. Also is it compulsory to disable tooltip.?

Comment: Sorry. Now I disabled enableMouseTracking, so (chart.series[i].graph.d === this.getAttribute("d")) condition gives me a point but the hover line is not highlighted.

Comment: Hi Pratik Rawlekar, to highlight the hover line, you have to add proper styles to `.highcharts-series path:hover`, like in my example.

Comment: Yes, After adding this style it worked. But I think, there is a zIndex issue now. Because which the hovered line is not visible at some points.

Comment: To solve this problem, you can use `toFront` method on `series.graph.parentGroup` element: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zh2tnwd4/

Comment: Thanks. It worked. What changes I need to make in order to show result values in tooltip .?

Comment: You would have to use `refresh` method on tooltip and right `formatter` function: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xbj3c1ah/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182505/discussion-between-pratik-rawlekar-and-ppotaczek).